# Deforming a sprite until texture no longer contiguous - how to maintain contact -detection?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

Still working on my space Invaders clone and I want to add the destructible bases at the bottom of the screen :

[image]

I've worked out how I can modify the appearance of the shield by having the bombs and the shield contact each other and then in didBegincontact, create an SKCropNode from a mask for the bomb's explosion and the current texture of the shield and then take the rendered texture with view's `texture(from: node)` method and updating the shield's texture & physicsBody from the new texture.

However - when there is a hole blown through the center of the shield, such that the shield's texture is no longer contiguous (e.g. the left-most shield in the picture), the generated physicsBody only covers the left-hand portion of the texture. Thus any bombs hitting the right-hand part of the shield won't be detected.

How can I have my shield break into multiple pieces and keep contact detection working?

Possible solutions:

- Somehow scan the new texture and create multiple physicsBoies which
  are either assigned to a single SKSpriteNode using
  `SKPhysicsbody(bodies: [SKPhysicsBody])`. If, as it appears, the
  SKPhysicsBody is generated from the top-left of the texture, then
  maybe rotate the texture through 90 degrees 4 times to generate 4
  physicsBodies?
- Use some sort of alpha-masking (so that the destroyed parts of the
  shiled are clear) and keep the physicsBody of the shield in the
  original shape and when dBC is called, check the colour of the pixels
  at the contact point/under the bomb - if they are 'clear', then take 
  no action and allow the bomb to fall through unimpeded until
  didEndContact is called indicating that the bomb is clear of the
  shield.
- Use a simple `intersectsRect` between the bomb and the shield and
  then check the pixel colour under the bomb - if clear, don't do
  anything.

===================================================

Update : See below for sprite texture damage working when not split. The brown base is the original one showing the first damage (physicsBody shows the original base, the texture shows the dame). The green base has had it's physics body recalculated:

[image]

Update: See below for the physics body when the texture is split. The brown is the original shield, the small indent is the 'new' damage. The physicsBody only maps to the left-hand portion of the image.

[image]

Comment: You should just be using SKPhysicsBody(texture),  every time your shield texture changes, give it a new body with the new texture, if it is not forming the correct body,  then place the new texture into a temp sprite node so you can see what is being generated,  I am almost positive I created bodies before with holes in the middle of them.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - doesn't work  unless I'm doing something wrong. See my update.

Comment: When i get time ill see what i come up with

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - thanks. I've added a screenshot to show the bomb damage/cropnode trick working. I have an Xcode Playground to test this if you want a copy.

Comment: Just played with it,  looks like it cant be done

Comment: you are better off not using physics bodies, and just checking if a pixel exists at that point

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks - I was worried that might be the case. An alternative approach would be to build the base out of many small sprites, each with their own physics bodies. I'm not sure how you can determine the colour of a specific pixel on-screen.

Comment: I wouldn't make many tiny sprites, that is ridiculous lol,  if your target is iOS 9 or later (It really should be at this point)  you can do something like this https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/3anrh9/how_do_i_get_the_color_data_of_3_points_in_my/

Comment: @Knight0fDragon. Thanks for the link. I might try making the bases out of 10-15 sprites and see how performance is affected.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - 3 bases of 30 blocks each and no slowdown so far :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I gave up with deforming the SKTexture of the base and instead implemented the base as about 30 small blocks, each with their own physicsBody and each of which is removed completely once it's hit.

I was concerned about performance but these are static blocks and so far, performance is still good. The overall graphic effect is OK too:

[image]

I may change the block textures to give them rough edges and experiment with replacing each block's texture with a smaller, more-dameged one the first time it is hit, for a more crumbling appearance.

Comment: Good to know. What's the lowest device you've tested this on?

Comment: Just my 6s at the moment.

Comment: DOH! That's the second fastest phone of all time. Only beaten by the 7. That low resolution and CPU/GPU combo, it's amazingly fluid. Perhaps the iPhone SE is a little faster. If you can find one, second hand, and cheap, the iPhone 6 Plus is the new iPhone 4. It struggles.

Comment: @Confused - good point. I just fired up my old iPhone 5 (not the 's') with iOS 9.3 and it ran absolutely perfectly on that with not a hint of slowdown.

Comment: Achievement unlocked! What else is in that drawer? I suspect a Palm Trio, but no blackberrys ;)